# Could it hurt my grad school application if I state a secondary research interest in which I have little experience?

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-process, undergraduate, research-undergraduate, machine-learning

**Background:** CS Undergrad applying to CS PhD USA.

I am interested in this 'X' domain but have not really invested time to do 'research' in it because it is computationally very demanding and I do not have access to such resources.

I have covered a good amount of theory in the topic but that doesn't add up to much unless I can show some form of practical implementation. That's just how the domain is.

I would really love to explore/research in the domain during my graduate tenure.

**Question:** Will it make me look bad if I say so while applying to graduate programs?

*Note:* I have good amount of research done in my current domain 'Y' and I will be mentioning that I will want to primarily want to work on that during my graduate tenure. But this domain 'X' has few avenues I would like to explore because it has shown to be beneficial when applied in 'Y'. Apart from that, the field on its own is extremely interesting to me.

Comment: I assume X is deep learning and the resources are GPUs?

Comment: Yup! I am aware of cloud GPUs but I don't have any form of financial backing!

Comment: For sure, the charges for cloud GPUs add up fast. For learning purposes, you can always choose a small dataset and run just a few epochs on CPU -- that's a good way to learn PyTorch and so forth. But I agree it'll be hard to get publication-quality results that way.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I do. I try to manage my work load between colab and Kaggle. Another issue is that in my country we don't have access to "colab pro" :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I seriously doubt it will make much difference.** You say you primarily want to work on Y, and your research experience is in Y, so you'll be judged as "a prospective Y student." If applying X to Y is a reasonable thing to do, then saying you're interested in X shouldn't hurt you at all. But without any real background in X, it also probably won't help you much.